# Mavericks OS X Update Freezing after restart

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, macbook-air

I just tried to update my 10.7 (Lion) 2010 MacBook Air to Mavericks but it's now freezing after it restarts (done that twice yet).

When I hard reboot the computer, it just starts the installation again and freezes at the end - sometimes showing it encountered a problem.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you kindly post the error message you received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait longer. The installation process isn't complete.

Comment: You mean wait even though the installation program tells me it encountered a problem and my mac is obviously frozen ?

Comment: @JohnThillaye If the installation program specifies a problem then it would be wise to specify this in the question.

Comment: Long wait, but waiting is the right move.

Comment: I tried a fourth time and let my computer working alone for a couple of hours, dunno if it froze or not but in the end it worked !

Comment: @JohnThillaye Good to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Macbook Air 2013 i7 500GB SSD OS X 10.8
When it said 'less than one minute' it was in fact 7 minutes. Conclusion: you probably have to wait for quite a long time. Progress monitor is flaky.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Maverick on iMac 27" late 2011 version.
Freezed at start. Rebooted 3 times, still freezed.
Unplugged power cable and pressed power for 3 sec.
Came back ok!

Answer (score 0):

No solution, but one useless attempt that you needn't waste your time on.

I installed Mavricks on three computers without problem, then experienced the same issue installing that others have encountered,  and the same freezing - or glacial progress in booting up- that makes my ca. 2011 iMac useless.

I ran Diskwarrior from the CD, rebuilt the directory, checked all folders, ran the hardware test. Everything was apparently fine... but the problems remain. Try something else.